# Generate String from Regexp

Tags: php, regex

I'm curious if there is a way to generate the list of valid options from a regexp... something like this.  Any ideas or hints welcome!

I want to do this in my PHP Code where I need to generate each possible outcome.  You can see what I'm looking for here: http://uttool.com/text/regexstr/default.aspx

Expression: `/(admin|agent)/Cutomers/View`

Output Valid Options
Array
0] '/admin/Customers/View'
1] '/agent/Customers/View'

Comment: Careful what you ask for. This could lead to an exponential output.

Comment: The expressions are simple OR operations in most cases so the output will be limited.  However I need to do this in my code so I'm not sure If I need to write something to parse it or if something already exist.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776286/given-a-string-generate-a-regex-that-can-parse-similar-strings/776323#776323. There is a link to a free web-based "regex by example" generator.

Comment: I'm not looking on how to generate a regex.  I'm looking to generate valid strings from a regex.  If you see the site that outputs what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've tried something like this:

```
function builder($string){
    $strend = explode('/',$string); 
    array_splice($strend,0,2);
    $strend=implode('/',$strend);
    preg_match('/\/(.*?)\//',$string,$m);
    $arr = explode('|',str_replace(array('(',')'),'',$m[1]));
    $resp = array();
    foreach($arr as $v){
        $resp[] = '/'.$v.'/'.$strend;
    }
    return $resp;
}
$str = '/(admin|agent|client)/Customers/View';
var_dump(builder($str));
```

Comment: This works for what I need right now so I will accept it.  Plus it can be expanded for slightly more complex expressions.  From what I can tell there is not much for a library out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a graphical representation here https://www.debuggex.com/

/(admin|agent)/Cutomers/View

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Z2OE3buBz1aDxQik)

If you have a dictionnary you can test against your regexp, without it is not possible juste imagine /.*/toto/tutu

Comment: any idea of a php library or function that would let me do this? I need to do this in my code.

Comment: Do what ? Have a dictionary of all url to test against your regexp ?