# Learning a regex from strings?

Tags: regex, machine-learning

Given some strings, is there some algorithm (and program that implement such an algorithm) that can create a regex which matches some of the given strings and not the other given strings?

I like the regex can generalize well on other strings not given (just like machine learning algorithms)

I am not restricted to any particular regex flavor.  Thanks.

Comment: One of such regexes would be `/string1|string2|.../`. If you want anything "smarter" than that, explain how exactly.

Comment: Right. I think i want something smarter than that, probably I should also give some strings that shouldn't be matched. and I like the regex can generalize well on other strings not given (just like machine learning algorithms)

Comment: Nope, we're not there yet. What you're asking for would be very difficult even for humans, and machine learning usually tries to do well on tasks that humans are good at.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at similar questions: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616292/is-it-possible-for-a-computer-to-learn-a-regular-expression-by-user-provided-e) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776286/given-a-string-generate-a-regex-that-can-parse-similar-strings?lq=1).

[Someones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616292/is-it-possible-for-a-computer-to-learn-a-regular-expression-by-user-provided-e/621125#621125) there argue that it is impossible in principle, [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776286/given-a-string-generate-a-regex-that-can-parse-similar-strings/776323#776323) suggest tools for that.

I'm not sure that [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_of_regular_languages) wasn't in these questions, so check it; also try to google by "pattern induction" or "regular expression induction" ([example paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5949679) for URL regexps).