# Generating a URL pattern when provided a set of 5 or so URLs

Tags: java, algorithm, string, url, design-patterns

Provided with a set of URLs, I need to generate a pattern,

For example:

```
http://www.buy.com/prod/disney-s-star-struck/q/loc/109/213724402.html
http://www.buy.com/prod/samsung-f2380-23-widescreen-1080p-lcd-monitor-150-000-1-dc-8ms-1920-x/q/loc/101/211249863.html
http://www.buy.com/prod/panasonic-nnh765wf-microwave-oven-countertop-1-6-ft-1250w-panasonic/q/loc/66357/202045865.html
http://www.buy.com/prod/escape-by-calvin-klein-for-women-3-4-oz-edp-spray/q/loc/66740/211210860.html
http://www.buy.com/prod/v-touch-8gb-mp3-mp4-2-8-touch-screen-2mp-camera-expandable-minisd-w/q/loc/111/211402014.html
```

Pattern is

> http://www.buy.com/prod/[^~]*/q/loc/[^~]*.html

Comment: Do you mean a regular expression ?

Comment: In essence you want an algorithm which can "learn" a regexp from examples. I've asked this question on this topic, perhaps it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616292/is-it-possible-to-learn-a-regular-expression-by-user-provided-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach would be to split your URL into groups (say `url.split("/")`) and compare the resulting arrays. It the parts match, just add them as constant strings to the pattern. If they don't, add a pattern that matches all possible values. Here is a simple implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] urls = {
            "http://www.buy.com/prod/disney-s-star-struck/q/loc/109/213724402.html", 
            "http://www.buy.com/prod/samsung-f2380-23-widescreen-1080p-lcd-monitor-150-000-1-dc-8ms-1920-x/q/loc/101/211249863.html",
            "http://www.buy.com/prod/panasonic-nnh765wf-microwave-oven-countertop-1-6-ft-1250w-panasonic/q/loc/66357/202045865.html",
            "http://www.buy.com/prod/escape-by-calvin-klein-for-women-3-4-oz-edp-spray/q/loc/66740/211210860.html",
            "http://www.buy.com/prod/v-touch-8gb-mp3-mp4-2-8-touch-screen-2mp-camera-expandable-minisd-w/q/loc/111/211402014.html"
    };

    String all = "[^/]+";
    String[] pattern = urls[0].split("/");
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        String parts[] = urls[i].split("/");

        // TODO handle urls with different number of parts
        for (int j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++) {
            // intentionally match by reference
            if (pattern[j] != all && !pattern[j].equals(parts[j])) {
                pattern[j] = all;
            }
        }
    }

    // build pattern - use [^/]+ as a replacement (anything but a '/')
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        buf.append(pattern[i] == all ? all : Pattern.quote(pattern[i]));
        buf.append("/");
    }
    // stip last "/"
    buf.setLength(buf.length() - 1);

    // compile pattern
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(buf.toString());

    // output
    System.out.println(p.pattern());
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(p.matcher(urls[i]).matches());
    }

}
```

Here's the output of this example:

```
\Qhttp:\E/\Q\E/\Qwww.buy.com\E/\Qprod\E/[^/]+/\Qq\E/\Qloc\E/[^/]+/[^/]+
true
true
true
true
true
```

As you see, the pattern looks a bit weird. That's due to the Pattern quoting. Nevertheless, the pattern matches all urls from this example. There's some work left though, most noteably handling urls with different number of parts after split and common suffixes (.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I've done a similar thing. My code works for URLS with same number of parts(I've gone with the assumption that all products are at the same level in the domain tree). I was just looking for some ideas to go about generating RegEx for URLS with different number of parts.

Thanks

Comment: @ryan this highly depends on your requirements. you could even say that such urls just don't have a common pattern. I thing it would be best if you give some examples (obviously examples that are a bit more complex than what you've been able to do yourself) and an expected pattern. If you want the algorithm to decide what's best suited, it's getting *extremely* complex (as in the question @DR linked above).

Comment: Ok, here's an example.

http://cgi.ebay.com/NEW-SKIP-HOP-Zoo-Packs-Baby-Kids-Animal-Backpack-MOUSE_W0QQitemZ160407569887QQcmdZViewItemQQptZLH_DefaultDomain_0?hash=item25590945df

http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/Harley-davidson-softail-41mm-lower-sliders_W0QQitemZ180474968580QQcmdZViewItemQQptZMotorcycles_Parts_Accessories?hash=item2a05257a04#ht_500wt_1182

This should give me http://cgi.motors.ebay.com/[^~]*
Or take this case. Here, say, bbb occurs in every URL
http://aaaa/bbb/ccc.html
http://aaaa/rr/bbb/d.html
http://bbb/e.html
My pattern would be something like
 http://[^~/]*/bbb/[^~]*.html

Comment: Actually, both example patterns you gave won't match all of the URLs, but I think I know what you meant. Implementing this is a bit more complex than what I currently provided. I don't have time to provide something right now. But maybe I find some time to solve this tomorrow - it looks like a fun challenge for a lazy Saturday afternoon :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this tool **[txt2re](http://www.txt2re.com/)** 
A nice online tool, where you enter an example string and it generates a regexp that matches it for you.

txt2re describes itselfs as:

> headache relief for programmers ::
>   regular expression generator