# Detecting a dynamic pattern with Spacy and extracting the variables

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, nltk, spacy

How could I use spacy to detect a pattern like:

```
mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 06/05/21
```

I want to detect the following patterns:

- mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 06/05/21
- mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 02/04/21
- mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 01/02/21
- ....

As you could see the date changes but everything remains the same. How can I use spacy to create a pattern matcher, that tells if the input string has the same pattern? Also, If the pattern is detected, I want to extract the date. Is that possible with Spacy?

I went through, https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching but not sure where to start.

**EDIT**
Given a group of dynamic phrases as above, is there a way to identify the  variables within the phrases?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect them with the matcher, using the code like

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [{'ORTH': 'mygov-24.mygov.ca'}, {'ORTH':'-'}, {'ORTH':'last'}, {'ORTH':'updated'}, {'ORTH':':'}, 
           {'ORTH': {'REGEX':r'^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?$'}}];
matcher.add("last_updated", [pattern])

text = r'It was here, mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 06/05/21. Next: mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 02/04/21. And one more: mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 01/02/21'
doc = nlp(text)

matches = matcher(doc)

matches = matcher(doc, as_spans=True)
for span in matches:
    print(span.text)
```

Output:

```
mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 06/05/21
mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 02/04/21
mygov-24.mygov.ca - last updated: 01/02/21
```

The `^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?$` regex matches a token that

- `^` - starts with
- `\d{1,2}`  - one or two digits
- `/` - then has a `/`
- `\d{1,2}/` - then has one or two digits and `/`
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?:\d{2})?` - additionally optional two digits
- `$` - end of token.

Comment: Is it possible to detect dynamic variables given X number of phrases? I need to detect variables in the phrases. Manually defining a regex will not be optimal

Comment: @Amanda You need to explain that in the question, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Updated. Given a group of dynamic phrases as above, is there a way to identify the variables within the phrases? Regex based solution would be avaialble without using Spacy

Comment: @Amanda Do you think Spacy will guess any patterns for you? This is not possible. You still need to specify them yourself.

Comment: Given n number of sentences, is there a way to identify the pattern and detect the variable? I am looking for something similar to the flow here https://youtu.be/B34gHahWX_s

Comment: @Amanda There is no way to do it "easily". There are special [tools](https://www.regexmagic.com/) for that. Spacy is not meant to be used like that anyway. Also, see [How to auto generate regex from given list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880402/how-to-auto-generate-regex-from-given-list-of-strings).

Comment: @Amanda [This Github repo](https://github.com/iuliux/RegExTractor) contains code that can convert a list of strings into a regex that can work the way you need. For Python3, you will need to fix `print` statements.

Comment: Did you see the video I shared?

Comment: The repo that you shared fails to create a generic regex for date / numbers.