# regular expression - comment out all lines containing the word "logging"

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to mass comment out all the lines referring to logging in a code.
I am using notepad ++ and ideally this would be achievable by replacing all the lines being like

```
< some text > logging
```

by

```
# < some text > logging
```

Sorry in advance to ask this kind of question on SO, but I'm kind of stuck , and I'm sure this can be useful to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notepad++,

Search "`^(.*) logging`" 
Replace "`#\1 logging`"

Make sure search mode is "Regular expression"

Answer (score 1):

Find with `(?=.*logging)^` and replace with `#`

**Eplanation:**

`(?=.*logging)` will `lookahead` for word *logging* and if present search for beginning of string with `^`

[image: Notepad ++ Regex replace.]

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cjx7FV/1/)**

Comment: @jimbasquiat: It's a Regex Tester. You enter your regex in first input box and content to search in second(which is large). Optional substitution can be done in third box which appears when you click on **Substitution** at bottom.

Comment: ok i see. Is there any site that you know that can create the regex?

Comment: @jimbasquiat: TL;DR No !

Comment: Well, there actually exist some. Like for example [this](http://buildregex.com/).  But learning regex really isn't that hard for most of the stuff.  And you can learn also from the explain plan on a site like that regex tester.

Comment: @LukStorms: That one is good. But still needs user input in creating regex.

Comment: Oh so you mean there's none that can discover the pattern from a list of strings and guess a regex for it. Yeah, probably not. That would need an AI...

Comment: @LukStorms: Exactly !

Comment: Then again. This is stackoverflow, and ... [it's been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196049/regular-expression-generator-reducer).  [This one](http://kemio.com.ar/tools/lst-trie-re.php) seems to work even. O_o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143104/discussion-between-rahul-and-lukstorms).

Answer (score 1):

Find what : `^.*logging$`
Replace with: `# $0`
Search mode: Regular expression

$0 is a variable for the match.
And the regex matches a line that ends with "logging". 
So replacing it with `# $0` puts a `#` at the start of a line that ends with `logging`.

> ^  : start of a line
>   .* : zero or more characters
>   $  : end of a line

And to a avoid commenting lines that are already are commented?
Adding a negative lookahead helps with that:

Find what: `^(?!\s*#).*logging$`