# Machine Learning - Software to learn file formats by example

Tags: machine-learning, file-format

My program can read several dozen file formats, using the traditional approach where I write procedural code for each file format. Most of these formats have their own unique loader library, their own bugs, their own limitations, and the whole thing is a huge time sink for me. I'd like to support a ton of other formats, but they're mostly not worth my time because they're not popular enough.

I'd like to replace my existing loaders with a single loader powered by a file format descriptor. I'm certain that someone has created software to learn file formats by example. My existing loaders would make excellent fitness functions for those formats, and I can write fitness functions for new formats too.

My question is, what software can I use to "learn" file formats by example, and how can I convert that "learning" into a descriptor for use with a generic loader?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you limit it in some massive ways, I don't think you're likely to get very far. This would be ideal but beyond the current state of the art. For an arbitrary formats, you cannot do this, for example if I give you 200 JPGs,PNGs,BMPs and GIFs it very highly unlikely that a learning system can learn the formats.

Here are some problems researchers have looked at:

- Learning a regular expression from examples: look at this question:
  [Is it possible for a computer to "learn" a regular expression by user-provided examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616292/is-it-possible-for-a-computer-to-learn-a-regular-expression-by-user-provided-e),
  for example
- Information extraction: I give you a list of classified ads from the
  newspaper, for example apartments for rent. You need to extract the
  number of bedrooms, the rent, the deposit and the size of the unit.
  You can read more about it here:
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction

Comment: So a machine can't learn every possible file format by example, but that shouldn't stop me. Where formats have complexities like compression, I would of course provide a decompression function. If some file format is just too complex, I can write a loader like I have. I think most file formats aren't beyond the reach of a learning algorithm, and I'd like to do what I can.