# Get PHP Regex automatic

Tags: php, regex

is there any tool or something which provide you PHP Regex after you submit some links.

If I put link `http://vk.com/video216479284_169096951` the output is something like this `~/video([0-9a-z_]+)~i

I'm just asking. I'm not familiar with PHP Regex, and I need to write a couple of them for some websites. If there's no such thing, then suggest me where to start learning PHP Regex.`

Comment: Unfortunately Regex is a complex beast for those unfamiliar with it because it is as flexible as you want it to be. What you use depends on what you're trying to filter/match for.  You can try http://regex101.com/ to check for how to structure and test your attempts. There are also many quick references such as http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm where you can learn what the uses are.

Comment: It's still possible to write a program that ["learns" a regex from multiple examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616292/is-it-possible-for-a-computer-to-learn-a-regular-expression-by-user-provided-e).

Answer (score 2):

[This is a nice explanation](http://www.regexmagic.com/autogenerate.html) why you can't do what you want to do.

> **Computers Cannot Read Your Mind**
>
> A lot of people are looking for a program that can automatically generate regular expressions for them. The program would only take examples of valid matches as input, and produce the proper regular expression as output, inferring the user's idea of "proper" as by magic. Unfortunately, no computer program will ever be able to generate a meaningful regular expression based purely on a list of valid matches. Let me show you why.
>
> Suppose you provide the examples 111111 and 999999. Which regular expression should the computer generate?
>
> 1. A regex matching exactly those two examples: (?:111111|999999)
> 2. A regex matching 6 identical digits (\d)\1{5}
> 3. A regex matching 6 ones and nines [19]{6}
> 4. A regex matching any 6 digits \d{6}
> 5. Any of the above four, with word boundaries, e.g. \b\d{6}\b
> 6. Any of the first four, not preceded or followed by a digit, e.g. (?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)
>
> As you can see, there are many ways in which examples can be generalized into a regular expression. The only way for the computer to build a predictable regular expression is to require you to list all possible matches. Then it could generate a search pattern that matches exactly those matches, and nothing else. Usually, providing an exhaustive list of matches is exactly what we're trying to avoid. And when you do have an exhaustive list of all possible matches, an optimized plain text search processing the whole list at once will be as fast as or faster than a regex search. The plain text search can be optimized to scan the text only once, without backtracking like regular expressions do.

To find PHP regex reference just begin with the right keyword.
You should search for "pcre" instead of searching for "PHP regex".