# Is possible to read collection of strings and return a Regexp?

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a collection of files from multiple sources.

Each file contains strings like:

```
File 1: A) B) C) D) E) 
File 2: a) b) c) d) e)
File 3: a. b. c. d. e.
File 4: a- b- c- d- e-
(...)
```

I know I could code all possible patterns beforehand, but I'd rather make it automatically.

Is it possible to make a program to read the file and *figure* the pattern?
Ex:

```
File 1: A) B) C) D) E) # => [ABCDE]\)
File 2: a) b) c) d) e) # => [abcde]\)
File 3: a. b. c. d. e. # => [abcde]\.
File 4: a- b- c- d- e- # => [abcde]-
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to do [here](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg) and [here](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/). Creates a regex trie via ternary tree.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616292/is-it-possible-for-a-computer-to-learn-a-regular-expression-by-user-provided-e

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/5395777/128421. You should be able to build something based on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for a computer to "learn" a regular expression by user-provided examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616292/is-it-possible-for-a-computer-to-learn-a-regular-expression-by-user-provided-e)

Answer (score 1):

[Regexp.union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) is smart enough to escape the parens, but that is it.

```
str = "A) B) C) D) E)"
p re = Regexp.union(*str.split) # => /A\)|B\)|C\)|D\)|E\)/
```

Perl's [Regexp::assemble](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Regexp-Assemble-0.35/Assemble.pm) might be able to do this, AFAIK there is no Ruby equivalent.