# Generate RegExr for a String

Tags: java, regex

I need to generate a regExr for the below String pattern.

> A:B:C:D

where **A** should contain only Strings and **B** can contain both String and a digits and **C** should be a String and **D** should only be the digits.

I created RegExr myself and its working.

```
[a-zA-Z]+(:)+[a-zA-Z1-9]+(:)+[a-zA-Z]+(:)+[1-9]+
```

But is there a better regExr for the pattern I want something bit shorter than mine? Or mine is ok?

I am using Java8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for a computer to "learn" a regular expression by user-provided examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616292/is-it-possible-for-a-computer-to-learn-a-regular-expression-by-user-provided-e)

Comment: You do know that `(:)+` means *one-or-more* colons, right? Seems you want exactly one colon, and you don't need to capture it. Also, a `0` is a digit too, you know. So this is what you need: `[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+`

Comment: @Andreas exactly. Thanks..

Comment: The regex could be *shortened* by specifying the [case-insensitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag: `(?i)[a-z]+:[a-z0-9]+:[a-z]+:[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RegEx only captures the `:`.

This RegEx works for "Hello:hel35a:ahelkj:684579" and captures the whole String.

```
 ([A-Za-z]+:(?:[A-Za-z]|\d)+:[A-Za-z]+:\d+)
```

Comment: What is the benefit of capturing the whole regex in a capturing group? Your regex [`([A-z]*:(?:[A-z]|\d)*:[A-z]*:\d*)`](https://regex101.com/r/R3V2J5/1) also matches `_:_:_:` , `:::` or `[\]^_`:_:_:` because `[a-Z]` [matches more than you think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret). The OP commented that it should not match underscores. Using the asterix `*` means repeat zero or more times. That means that you made everything optional except the colons `:`

Comment: [`([A-z]*:(?:[A-z]|\d)*:[A-z]*:\d*)`](https://regex101.com/r/R3V2J5/1) does match `_:_:_:` because the `\d*` matches zero or more times. You can check the link.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\d` instead `1-9`(if 0 is permitted).

Answer (score 2):

You can use \d for digits and if you don't mind accepting the underscore you can also use the \w for the [a-zA-Z].

Your Regexp could become:

`[\w]+:[\w\d]+:[\w]+:[\d]+`

Comment: Thanks. There shouldn't be any underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex code looks completely fine if you have to avoid **0** and **_** otherwise you can use above examples. If you want to pass it as parameter then try assinging it to a string, that will be more  convinient(*which I haven't tried yet!*).

Comment: What "above examples"?

Answer (score 0):

You Expression looking good. If you want more regEx operations use this site it is very helpful [txt2re](https://txt2re.com/)

Comment: Regex is not good, since it would match e.g. `A:::B:C:D`, and it wouldn't match `A:B:C:0`

Answer (score 0):

You might use a word boundary `\b` if you don't' want your match to be part of a larger match. (Or use anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and end of the string)

For example `a:1a:b:0` would match, but `a:1a:b:0a` does not because it has an `a` at the end.

To match a digit 0-9 you could use `\d` and to match a single colon you could just use `:` without a quantifier `+` or a capturing group `()`

Your regex could look like this:

*note the case insensitive flag `/i` in the demo to use `[a-z]` instead of `[A-Za-z]`*

[`\b[a-z]+:[a-z\d]+:[a-z]+:\d+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/60gJ8H/1)

Java:

[`\\b[a-z]+:[a-z\\d]+:[a-z]+:\\d+\\b`](http://rextester.com/RQTM52831)